# Regular Expression: How to capture text left of "="

Tags: c#, regex, devexpress

I'm trying to capture anything on the left side of an equals sign (without the equals sign) from this.

> `MSG_TYPE=X12S4F3S3\r\nASID=123456789012\r\n`

I have used `(\w*)=` but this seems to pick up the equals and the prevailing `n` of the `/n`

This is for `.net`.

Sorry, forgot to mention the text is contained within an RTF Document, so basic substring functions are not possible as I'm trying to create CharacterProperties from DocumentRanges.

```
Regex regEx = new Regex (@"(\w*)=");
DocumentRange [] docRanges = m_rtfTranslation.Document.FindAll (regEx);

for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < docRanges.Length; nIndex++)
{
    CharacterProperties cp = m_rtfTranslation.Document.BeginUpdateCharacters (docRanges [nIndex]);
    cp.ForeColor = Color.SlateBlue;
    m_rtfTranslation.Document.EndUpdateCharacters (cp);
}
```

Comment: -1: the title `Regular Expression can't remove the equals` and the sentence `this seems to pick up the equals` don't really match. Please put minimal effort into asking before you expect minimal effort in answering.

Comment: That's a valid sentence, I don't want the equals and what I have tried picks up the equals, which I don't want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need a regexp for this? A simple substring would work:

```
var lhs = msg.Substring(0, msg.IndexOf("=")) // MSG_TYPE
```

If you need to match or capture:

```
var lhs = Regex.Match(msg, @"(.*)=");
Console.WriteLine(lhs.Groups[1].Value);
```

If you need a regexp to replace the left hand side of `=`:

```
var lhs = Regex.Replace(msg, @"(.*)=", "<green>$1</green>");
Console.WriteLine(lhs);
```

Yields:

```
<green>MSG_TYPE</green>X12S4F3S3\r\n<green>ASID</green>123456789012\r\n
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this is inside an RTF Document.  I'm trying to colour the left side of the equals to make it more visual for users.

Comment: It's not a replace I'm after, I want to match, let me extend the question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @Sres Ok, added a simple example of that. Sorry but your question is a little confusing.

Comment: I'm going to have to raise this with DevExpress as I don't think this is working as intended internally to their software.  Thanks for the help, your code works, just not when put into the control.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace(
    @"MSG_TYPE=X12S4F3S3\r\nASID=123456789012\r\n",
    @"([^=]+)(=.*?\\r\\n)",
    @"[color]$1[/color]$2"
));
```